# .Xml file is not packaged when I build jar

Tags: java, xml, jar, package

This is the structure of my project in IntellijIDEA

[Structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DomcG.png)

When I build my jar file it doesn't package the characters.xml file.

```
Document doc = builder.parse("characters.xml");
```

This is how I source it in the code. There is obviously a mistake here but I can't figure out where to put it and what path I should write.

Comment: Do not put pictures of text in your question.  Copy and paste the text directly.  If it’s code, indent it by four spaces so it appears in a code block.

Comment: how about the structure? which i cant just paste it as text?

Comment: The structure is okay as an image.  Text would be better, if you have knowledge of the right Unicode characters (like ‘▼’, ‘▶’, and ‘└’) and if you’re willing to take the time to type it in.

Comment: Ok done, now can you help me with my question?

Comment: Out of curiosity, is sample.xml present in your .jar file?  If it is, that would suggest you should move characters.xml to the src\sample directory.

Comment: Do you mean the sample.fxml? yes it is. I tried that. but i dont know what path i should write in the Document doc = builder.parse("characters.xml"); Because in any computer the jar could be moved anywhere, the path cant be static..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [documentation for DocumentBuilder.parse(String)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/xml/parsers/DocumentBuilder.html#parse-java.lang.String-) states:

> Parse the content of the given URI as an XML document and return a new DOM `Document` object.

`"characters.xml"` is technically a valid URI, but it is a relative URI, and there is no base URI against which to resolve it.

To read a file inside a .jar, you use [Class.getResource](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getResource-java.lang.String-) or [Class.getResourceAsStream](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getResourceAsStream-java.lang.String-).  An example would be:

```
Document doc;
try (InputStream stream = Controller.class.getResourceAsStream("characters.xml")) {
    doc = builder.parse(stream);
}
```

Alternatively, you could convert the resource to a URI:

```
Document doc = builder.parse(
    Controller.class.getResource("characters.xml").toString());
```

Note that both Class.getResource and Class.getResourceAsStream return null if the argument is not a path of an existing jar entry.  You will need to move characters.xml into your src\sample directory.  You may want to verify that the .jar file contains characters.xml by examining it in your IDE’s “Files” area.